# @Intercepted vs InvocationContext

Tags: java, cdi, interceptor, java-ee-7

When implementing an `Interceptor`, is there a way to get the name of the actual (concrete) class being intercepted using the `InvocationContext` ?

Unless I am wrong, calling `ic.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getName()` will return the (extdended) interface / base abstract class?

Is the `@Intercepted` annotation the only way of getting the actual implementation being intercepted?

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I have used the following to get the name of the intercepted class:

```
public Object audit(InvocationContext invocation) throws Exception
{
    final String name = invocation.getTarget().getClass().getName();
    ...
```

The "target" in this context is the class that is being intercepted.

Comment: Yes this is correct, but if you intercept ```@AroundConstruct``` methods, it will be null, so be sure to check for null.